# Jquery find td containing hyperlink

Tags: jquery, select, text, hyperlink, html-table

I need to find a TD (lowest level) that contains a hyperlink text value.  For example:

```
<td>
  <a href....>Hours</a>
</td>
```

I would like to use jQuery to obtain the element and right justify the hyperlink text.  Here is what I am using (Obviously does not work).

```
$('td').filter(function(index) { return $(this).text().contains("Hours"); }).attr('style', "text-align:'right'");
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a dedicated selector in jQuery : [:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

```
$('td:contains("Hours")').attr('style', "text-align:'right'");
```

As I'm not sure of your question ("hyperlink" ?), if you're trying to get links in a table whose href contains "Hours", you can do this :

```
$('td a[href~="Hours"]').attr('style', "text-align:'right'");
```

EDIT : after having formatted the question, I think the second part is useless.